# How to merge 2 polygons from a single layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge, donut-polygons

I have created buffers around several points, but they come out in patches. Therefore I want to edit and merge them together. How do I do that in QGIS? The red circles shows the areas I want to join.[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

you "dissolve" polygons from the same layer, in this case, you would need to buffer with dissolve (there's an option in vector>geoprocessing). There must be a reason why your buffer doesn't connect in those places